# Ansible: Filtering with "contains"

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, aws-cli

I am searching for AMI IDs created on today's date.

My Ansible playbook is

```yaml
---
- name: List of AMIs created today
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:

  - name: Get today's date
    command: "date +'%Y-%m-%d'"
    register: result

  - name: Get AMIs list
    ec2_ami_info:
       filters:
         owner: self
         creation_date: "{{ result }}"
```

The Ansible module [`ec2_ami_info`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_ami_info_module.html) needs the exact [`creation_date`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_ami_info_module.html#return-images/creation_date) which is like `2018-11-30T08:33:08.000Z`. But the `date` command `result` value is `2018-11-30`.

Can I get AMI IDs which `creation_date` contains `2018-11-30`?

Comment: Might just be easier to register the output of your AMI list without the creation date filter, and then set_fact to filter the output into a new list.  Similar to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218486/ansible-querying-aws-amis

Comment: @MichaelGardner I tried using the above link.  `old_ami: "{{ amis.images | selectattr('creation_date','match','^{{ result.stdout}}') | list}}"`
where `result` is 30 days older date. But I am unable to get the list of amis. But in console I can see.

Comment: This is different from the question posted above.  If you have a new question, then you should create a new question.  Also, if you have found an answer to the question above, then you should post it as well.  It is ok to answer your own questions.